# What are the icons next to people's names?

Tags: xbox-360, call-of-duty-black-ops

When you play multiplayer, at the screen where you see how the teams are to be divided for the next game, occasionally there are icons next to people's names. What do these represent?

One of them is the speaker, that flashes when someone talks, but what are the rest? Sometimes there are a few that are matching, so does this indicate that the gamers are in a team?

Also, where do I go to find these types of little things out - like how to mute gamers quickly in match, etc? It used to be in the instructions booklet with the CD, but now it's not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's only a few of these I think. Here are the ones that i can remember off the top of my head.

The microphone looking one is someone in game chat, with a mic plugged in. Meaning they can hear you, you can hear them etc.

The one that you are probably talking about is kind of like a comic speach bubble. That means that that person is in party chat. Meaning they are chatting with other people and can't hear you.

It's impossible to know who's in a party with who so you can't nessisarily know that everyone is on the same "team". But you can often guess from clan tags and other similarities.

As far as finding out information, the best thing to do is find out via trial and error. You can always ask if you can't figure something out. :)

Also, to mute people either click on their names or if your in-game push the back button(aka select) scroll over their name and then hit "x".

Comment: Mute in game! Thanks for that one!!! Finally...peace.